# Get name of kwargs from method signature to flatten a method signature into a single dict using locals()

Tags: python-3.x, signature, keyword-argument

I have a class method of the form:

```
def _cool_method(arg1, arg2, **kwargs):
  <do pre-processing stuff>
  super()._cool_method(**flattened_kwargs)
```

where I want `flattened_kwargs` to be a `dict` like:

```
flattened_kwargs = {
    "arg1": value,
    "arg2" value,
    "kwargs_key1": value,
    "kwargs_key2": {"nestedarg1": value, "nestedarg2": value}
    "kwargs_key3": value,
}
```

I need to pass a single kwargs `dict` to the super call after some processing in the child method.

I have managed to figure out how to flatten the input signature into a single `dict` using `locals()`:

```
attrs = locals().copy()
attrs.pop("kwargs")
attrs.update(kwargs)
```

I would now like to convert this to a helper function to call in a number of child class methods.  However, the above code assumes that I know the name of `**kwargs` as defined by the method signature.  I would like to inspect this from the child method so that I don't need to hardcode an assumed key into the `pop()` call.

I understand that in Python 3.6 I should be using [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) and have managed to get this far:

```
def _get_signature_kwargs_key(f):
    keys = [k for k, v in signature(f).parameters.items() if v.kind == v.VAR_KEYWORD]
    return keys[0] if len(keys) == 1 else None


def flatten_signature_args(f, loc):
    kwargs_name = _get_signature_kwargs_key(f)
    attributes = loc.copy()
    # cater for method calls from classes, which include unwanted metadata
    for meta in ['__class__', 'self']:
        try:
            del attributes[meta]
        except KeyError:
            pass
    attributes.pop(kwargs_name)
    attributes.update(loc[kwargs_name])
    return attributes
```

For obvious reasons, the assumption of `VAR_KEYWORD` uniqueness appears reasonable.  However, is there a better approach to extracting this from the signature, or perhaps a better approach to my requirement for flattening the overall signature?

I'm also having to do a hack to remove meta keys when calling a class method, or it fails when I pass `self._cool_method` as the input function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with:

```
def get_signature_locals(f, loc):]
    return {k: v for k, v in loc.items() if k in signature(f).parameters}

def get_signature_kwargs_key(f):
    keys = [k for k, v in signature(f).parameters.items() if v.kind == v.VAR_KEYWORD]
    try:
        return keys.pop()
    except IndexError:
        return None

def flatten_signature_kwargs(func, loc):
    kwargs_name = get_signature_kwargs_key(func)
    attributes = get_signature_locals(func, loc)
    if kwargs_name:
        attributes.pop(kwargs_name)
        attributes.update(loc[kwargs_name])
    return attributes
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone prefers to flatten to args instead of kwargs, I have the following function:

```
def flatterargs(f, *args, **kwargs) -> tuple:
    p = signature(f).parameters
    missargs = list(p.keys())[len(args):]
    kwtoargs = [kwargs.get(m, p[m].default) for m in missargs]
    return args + tuple(kwtoargs)

# Sample use:

def foo(a, b, c=3, d=4, e=5):
        ...

print(flatterargs(foo, 1, 2))  # 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```